# Fly and Two Trains Riddle

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

> Two trains travel on the same track towards each other, each going at a speed of 50 kph. They start out 100km apart. A fly starts at the front of one train and flies at 75 kph to the front of the other; when it gets there, it turns around and flies back towards the first. It continues flying back and forth till the two trains meet and it gets squashed.
>
> How far did the fly travel before it got squashed?

The question is relatively simple - the trains take an hour to collide, and in an hour the fly would travel 75 km. However, the question got me wondering: Lets say you are given a time $t$ in hours(where $t< 1$) How many "rounds" would the fly make in $t$ time? A round  is defined as moving from one train to another and back. How would I model the equation?

Comment: Infinitely many "rounds" are made in any situation that results in the trains crashing as above--as you've evidently noticed, given the tag.

Comment: @Cameron. I'm not talking about the total amounts of rounds, but instead the amount of rounds over a specific amount of time. For example, the amount of rounds made in 30 minutes would be finite, wouldn't it?. Sorry, I should have clarified it in the question.

Comment: Ah! I see. Well, Marvis's answer should shed some light on the idea of this. Are you familiar with partial sums of a geometric series? If so, you can look at his answer with $a(1)=100$, then figure out the greatest $n$ for which the $n$th partial sum is less than the partial sum $$\sum_{t=1}^n\frac{a(t)}{125}=\sum_{t=1}^n\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^t=-1+\cfrac{1-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{4}{5}},$$ assuming that Marvis calculated correctly. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time taken to do the $n^{th}$ round is $\dfrac{a(n)}{(75+50)}$ where $a(n)$ is the distance between the two trains at the beginning of the $n^{th}$ round.

Note that $$a(n+1) = a(n) - (50+50) \times \dfrac{a(n)}{125} = \dfrac{a(n)}{5} = \dfrac{a(1)}{5^n}.$$
The distance travelled by the fly in the $n^{th}$ round is $75 \times \dfrac{a(n)}{125} = \dfrac{3}{5} a(n)$.

Hence, the total distance travelled by the fly is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{3}{5} a(n) = a(1) \dfrac{3}{5} \left( 1 + \dfrac15 + \dfrac1{5^2} + \cdots \right) = a(1) \dfrac{3}{5} \times \dfrac{5}{4} = \dfrac34 a(1)$$ which is nothing but $$\text{Speed of the fly} \times \underbrace{\dfrac{a(1)}{\text{Relative speed between the trains}}}_{\text{Time taken by the trains to collide}}$$
which makes sense.

If you want the total number of rounds the fly makes before the train collides, this amounts to the number of rounds till when $a(n) = 0$. However note that only as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $a(n) \rightarrow 0$. Hence, the fly will make $\infty$-rounds before the trains collide!

The time taken by the fly to make the first round is $$\dfrac{a(1)}{125}.$$ The time taken by the fly to make the $n^{th}$ round is $$\dfrac{a(n)}{125}.$$ Hence, the time taken till the $N^{th}$ round is $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{a(n)}{125} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{ \dfrac{a(1)}{5^{n-1}}}{125}$$

Hence, solve for $N$ in the equation $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{ \dfrac{a(1)}{5^{n-1}}}{125} = t$$
Setting $a(1) = 100$, we get that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(\dfrac15 \right)^n = \dfrac{5t}{4}$$
$$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac15 \right)^N - 1}{\left(\dfrac15 \right) - 1} = \dfrac{5t}{4}$$
$$1 - \left(\dfrac15 \right)^N = t$$ $$\left(\dfrac15 \right)^N = 1-t$$ Hence the number of rounds, $N$, made by the fly as a function of time $t$ is $$N = \dfrac{\log(1-t)}{\log(1/5)}$$